# Starting node server automatically when auto-scaling EC2 does not work

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

I would like to automatically run node server when instances are created (using forever). I am on Ubuntu 11.10 (Canonical), I followed the instructions here exactly on creating launch config using user script: http://alestic.com/2011/11/ec2-schedule-instance

I can't seem to get this to work. Below is my startup script:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                        

set -e -x

/home/MyUserName/node_modules/.bin/forever stopall
/home/MyUserName/node_modules/.bin/forever start node.js/app.js
```

The launch config is created using this cmd:

```
as-create-launch-config MyLC --image-id ami-b6a3f8f2 --user-data-file user-data-script.sh --instance-type m1.small
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue, I have to run forever as the user, not root, wonder why...like so:

`sudo -u MyUserName /home/MyUserName/node_modules/.bin/forever start node.js/app.js`

Comment: ha, that was going to be my next suggestion... usually startup issues are either fully qualified path problems or permissions problems :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you fully qualifying the `app.js` file? Could it just be this line?

```
/home/MyUserName/node_modules/.bin/forever start /home/MyUserName/node.js/app.js
```

Comment: Tried that, it's not working :( But if I just run that script directly in the instance, it works.